# routing a copy of every mailing list posting to another server

Tags: linux, postfix, procmail

I have a mailing list server running behind Postfix. I'm in the process of upgrading the ML software (on a separate VM) and would like to send it copies of production postings to make sure things are working correctly.

I've setup `always_bcc` in Postfix (on the ML host) to point to a local user (listmail) and then use `/etc/procmailrc` to send the message to my upgraded host in my test environment.

```
#  send copy of ML posts to lists.test
:0
* ^To:.*testlist@my.domain.com
!testlist@lists.test.mydomain.com
```

This seems to sort of work for "testlist" but when the individual emails go out from the list server, these also have `To:` set as *testlist@my.domain.com* which is going to require checking some other headers in the recipe as I only want to route the initial (OP) post.

The other issue is I don't want to write a recipe for every mailing list we have (over a few hundred) and then have to update it everytime a list is added or removed - so this means adding in some kind of `grep` or mysql query in the procmail recipe to see if `To:` is a valid ML.

Is there a better way to do this?

I've included `postconf -(n|M)` below:

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases,hash:/etc/mail/sympa/aliases
alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-lists-with-exclusions.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-owners.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-request.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-unsubscribe.cf,hash:/etc/mail/sympa/aliases,hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
default_privs = sympa
home_mailbox = .maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 60000000
mailbox_transport = smtp:[mx2.mydomain.com]:2525
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, lists.test.mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = lists.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.140.136.0/23
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/myrecipientmap
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination, lists.mydomain.com
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 5
smtp_host_lookup = native,dns
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
sympa_destination_recipient_limit = 1
sympabounce_destination_recipient_limit = 1
transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/transport_regexp
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual


# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
sympa      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=sympa argv=/usr/lib/sympa/bin/queue ${recipient}
sympabounce unix -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=sympa argv=/usr/lib/sympa/bin/bouncequeue ${recipient}
```

Comment: Procmail seems like an unnecessary complication here. Can't you just set up an alias for each list?

Comment: A single regex with all your lists could be generated from a file which enumerates them, but it's really not clear from your question what the resulting recipe should actually look like. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify which parts you need help with? This seems too broad but maybe it can be boiled down to something that a single person could tackle in a single answer.

Comment: you're probably right about procmail overly complicating things. I already had something similar setup and was trying to re-use some code. Not sure about using `aliases`. The software in use is `Sympa` and they auto-generate a special alias file just for the lists. Probably can't mess with it.

Comment: After some more reading, I think what this boils down to is another postfix "dual delivery" question (didn't know that's what it is called). I essentially want to deliver the ML posting to two different servers. I found [this](https://jyotishp.ml/tutorials/postfix/dual-delivery-for-postfix) article that might work. I think I would need to put all my MLs into the `bcc_map_to_relay` file.